# How do I use a form across several sites in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I've got a Kentico 8.2 multisite installation with 3 sites.

I've developed a very simple form for one of the sites. The form is included in the header and footer of the master template that gets reused across all 3 sites.

When I load my homepage on one of the other sites I get "required form 'Subscribe' does not exist".

I've gone through my page templates and marked them all as accessible to all 3 sites - how do I mark my form as usable by any of the subsites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **maartenvdh** says, BizForms are site specific only. However, you can use BizForms from one site on a another one. So you can create a "main" BizForm on one particular site and reuse it on another sites.

1. Go to the design tab of a page
2. Insert Online Form WebPart and edit its properties
3. On Form name field click on a Select button
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, that looks good. Wasn't looking forward to duplicating the form data across 3 separate sites.

Answer (score 0):

BizForms are site specific, so you cannot use one form for the three websites. You need to add the form for each website with the same codename and then it probably work.